# Omitting common template arguments for friend function

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote a red-black tree class and a friend function that joins two trees and other value.

My current code is working as follows:

```
// forward declarations
template <Containable K, typename V, typename Comp, bool AllowDup>
requires std::invocable<Comp, K, K>
class RedBlackTree;

template <Containable K, typename V, typename Comp, bool AllowDup, typename T>
RedBlackTree<K, V, Comp, AllowDup> join(
    RedBlackTree<K, V, Comp, AllowDup> &&tree1, T &&raw_value,
    RedBlackTree<K, V, Comp, AllowDup> &&tree2);

// actual class definition
template <Containable K, typename V, typename Comp, bool AllowDup>
requires std::invocable<Comp, K, K>
class RedBlackTree {
   // ...
// friend function declaration
template <Containable K_, typename V_, typename Comp_, bool AllowDup_, typename T>
  friend RedBlackTree<K_, V_, Comp_, AllowDup_> join(
    RedBlackTree<K_, V_, Comp_, AllowDup_> &&tree1, T &&raw_value,
    RedBlackTree<K_, V_, Comp_, AllowDup_> &&tree2);
};

// actual function implementation
template <Containable K, typename V, typename Comp, bool AllowDup, typename T>
RedBlackTree<K, V, Comp, AllowDup> join(
    RedBlackTree<K, V, Comp, AllowDup> &&tree1, T &&raw_value,
    RedBlackTree<K, V, Comp, AllowDup> &&tree2) {
   // ...
}
```

This code works correctly but I think this is extremely ugly.

In the `class RedBlackTree<K, V, Comp, AllowDup>`,
we already know template parameters `K, V, Comp, AllowDup`,
so I want to open friendship for only `join` functions that matches `K, V, Comp, AllowDup`.

So what I want is something like:

```
template <Containable K, typename V, typename Comp, bool AllowDup>
requires std::invocable<Comp, K, K>
class RedBlackTree {
   // ...
// friend function declaration
template <typename T>
  friend RedBlackTree join(
    RedBlackTree &&tree1, T &&raw_value,
    RedBlackTree &&tree2);
};
```

It doesn't compile, the compiler complains fail to match instantiations of `join`.
How can I do this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to befriend a partial specialization of `join` - only those specializations that have the first 4 parameters matching the specialization of `RedBlackTree`, with arbitrary 5th parameter. I don't believe there's a way to do that. You can befriend function template as a whole, with all its specializations (as you do in your original code), or a particular instance, e.g. `friend RedBlackTree join<K, V, Comp, AllowDup, int>(...);` I don't know of a way to befriend a subset, with some template parameters locked down while others remain free.

Comment: Your second attempt does something different entirely. For each instantiation of `RedBlackTree`, it declares a function template named `join` with a single template parameter. All those function templates overload the original 5-parameter template. The overload resolution picks them as a better match, but then the linker complains because none are actually implemented.